# Select by attributes appears to not work correctly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, select

This table:

```
ca     ca1
12333  123330
```

doing this query in Select_analysis:
in the `where` parameter.

```
ca = 'substring(ca1,1,5)'
```

gives empty feature layer

and this:

```
 ca <> 'substring(ca1,1,5)'
```

gives a layer identical to the original:

```
 ca     ca1
12333  123330
```

Shouldn't it be the opposite since in the first case the `where` is True and has the 5 first numbers in `ca1` similar to `ca`?

Comment: what do you write exactly ? If you use the quotes ' ' around the substring command, then it will not be interpreted as a command but as a string

Comment: Thank you very much.This was it.Can you clarify when to use quotes in the select analysis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL queries in ArcGIS use the single quotes to designate a string. Any group of character between single quotes is therefore handled like a string. If you want to call a function of a variable by its name, you should therefore not use the quotes. For instance, those two statements return true for your example row:

```
ca = substring(ca1,1,5)
```

(because ca is equal to '12333' and the substring(ca1,1,5) is equal to '12333'

```
ca = '12333'
```

on the other hand

```
ca = 'substring(ca1,1,5)'
```

is false because '12333' is not equal to 'substring(ca1,1,5)' (a string, not a function in this case)

and

```
ca = substring('ca1',1,2)
```

is false because the variable ca is not equal to the string 'ca' returned by substring function